# How do I write the resulting sound to a file?

Tags: java, arrays, audio

```
/**
* Plays the words, in order with a parameter-specified pause between each and writes the resulting sound out to a file
* @param pause the number of milliseconds to pause between words
* @param filename the name of the file to write
* @param path the path where the file should be written
* @throws InterruptedException 
*/

public void play(int pause, String filename, String path) throws InterruptedException {

    for (int i = 0; i < numWords; i++) {
        myWordArray[i].blockingPlay();
        Thread.sleep(pause);
    }

    Sound newSound = new Sound(myWordArray.getSamples());
    newSound.setMediaPath(path);
    newSound.write(filename);
}
```

This is what I have so far but it's not working..

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Comment: it has errors. i know it has something to do with the Sound newSound line.. possibly the mediaPath line as well

Comment: it says cant find symbol

Comment: If you ever ask for help, you need to provide all relevant information: the code, what you expect the code to do, and what the code actually does (including error messages). Leaving error messages out is like going to the doctor and refusing to tell her any of your symptoms.